# IE8 Javascript Performance issues

Tags: performance, internet-explorer

http://tinyurl.com/p3xkamq

this page is using a wordpress theme that seems to include javascripts that really trouble Internet Explorer 8 (gets extremely slow and unresponsive on the home and about page)
How can I find out which scripts are causing problems and/oror disable them for IE8 specifically?

Comment: how did you end up solving this?